# Tell intelliJ to compile module with scalac in a java project?

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea, compilation

I have a java project in intelliJ and I've added a few modules, one of which has scala code in it.

I want to tell intelliJ to compile this module with scalac not javac, but I can't figure out where to configure it, and when I try to compile it gives me this error, "Cannot create instance of scalac"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206001829-Project-configuration-explained:

> A module that requires compiling with Scalac should have a Scala facet attached.

And further down (what I think you want):

> To add Scala support to existing module:
>
> - Right-click the module in Project View, choose "Add Framework Support..."
> - Check "Scala" in technologies list (unavailable if module has Scala facet attached)
> - Provide a path to Scala installation (if not detected)

Comment: Unfortunately I did this already, but it didn't resolve the problem.

Comment: @RyanStull have you followed the other instructions in that document?

Comment: I'll take another look at it and let you know, thanks

Comment: Also, you might try deleting and reinstalling your Scala library.  If it got corrupted, that might cause the problem.  If something happened like you deleted your cached libs, IntelliJ doesn't detect that very well, so you'll have to re-download things.

Comment: I deleted and recreated the configuration for the module, didn't change anything, but it's working now. Thanks